# Install Ubuntu on Windows with BitLocker (Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crytp)

Tags: system-installation, windows

I have a Windows machine with BitLocker. I turned off BitLocker, created a new partition, restarted the machine and entered in the Ubuntu installation interface. I get blocked on a screen with a password input and the phrase "Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crytp". What should I do? Is this caused by BitLocker? I had Ubuntu installed before on this machine with disk encryption enabled, but this is a new Ubuntu on a bootable USB drive.

[image]

I don't have the partitions from the former Ubuntu installation, I have the following partitions on the laptop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu installation is encrypted. You must have selected the option to encrypt your installation.

You need to enter the encryption key that you set up when you installed Ubuntu. You will need to enter this key every time you boot Ubuntu to decrypt your system.

If you don't remember the password you created, or if you don't want your installation encrypted, then you need to start over and reinstall Ubuntu.

If this is a remnant from a former installation, then you need to use a disk utility to delete the partions associated with your former installation before you attempt to reinstall Ubuntu. You can run Disks (GNOME disk utility) from installation media when you choose the "Try Ubuntu" option.

As always, make sure your important data is backed up before making changes to partitions or operating systems. If you make a mistake, you may need to reinstall one or both operating systems.

Comment: I didn't select anything, Ubuntu is not installed, this is the first screen I see when I try to install.

Comment: Then you must have never deleted your former Ubuntu installation. You need to use a disk utility to prepare your system for a new installation. You need to remove the partitions associated with your former Ubuntu installation. You need unpartitioned free space anyway if you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: No, I don't have the partitions from the former installation. Everything was wiped when I installed Windows.

Comment: I've included the partitions on my question.

Comment: I also don't see where you intended to install Ubuntu because the partitions on that disk are all assigned and in use with no unpartitioned free space for you to install Ubuntu. Where were you planning on installing Ubuntu? Unfortunately, what you're claiming is impossible, so perhaps you didn't do what you thought you did, or there's other physical volumes attached to your computer. What you are seeing comes from an Ubuntu installation which cannot survive all volumes being completely formatted. Did you rely on the Windows installer to fully ease the disk? Because it doesn't actually do that.

Comment: I found the problem. In the boot menu there was one option "Ubuntu" that was from the from the former installation. I had to select the USB drive option.